# How to use viewport denoising on final render

Tags: eevee-render-engine

My final render looks completely different from my viewport. I figured out that the "viewport denoising" option is what's making the change. Does anyone know how to enable this in the final render?

Viewport (this is what I want the final to look like):
[image: Render samples 2 / Viewport samples 2 / viewport denoising on]

Viewport w/out viewport denoising:
[image: Render samples 2 / Viewport samples 2 / viewport denoising off]

Render (this is not what I want, but what I get):
[image: final render, same settings as before with viewport denoising on]

Comment: In my experience, viewport denoising largely compensates for a lack of render samples in the viewport - maybe reduce the samples of your render? Someone else had a similar problem here - https://blenderartists.org/t/is-there-any-way-to-turn-on-eevee-viewport-denoising-in-the-final-render/1318046 - though a solution is not outright mentioned, the users in the discussion seem to speculate this can be compensated for in the compositor.

Comment: I'm sorry, one thing I don't get: you have _Bloom_ in the viewport with _Denoising_ turned on, but when it's off the _Bloom_ is gone? Because that's the most apparent difference for me...